# sample_distorted_bounding_box() takes at least 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I run a simple code about **tf.sample_distorted_bounding_box()** :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

file_content = tf.read_file('download.jpg')

image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file_content)
image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)

float_image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)

example_img = tf.squeeze(float_image, 0)




begin, size, bbox_for_draw = tf.image.sample_distorted_bounding_box(
    tf.shape(example_img),
    min_object_covered=0.1,
    use_image_if_no_bounding_boxes = True)
```

But I got the Error:

```
 use_image_if_no_bounding_boxes = True)
TypeError: sample_distorted_bounding_box() takes at least 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I use  ubuntu16.04  TF1.5